# Batch Linux installation in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, grub

I have the following question.

When I install manually a Linux (say, CentOS or RHEL) in VirtualBox,
at start up the grub menu appears (Installation CD in virtual tray).
Then I can manually choose a type of installation and afterwards, depressing tab key,
fill the details of the installation itself.

Suppose now that I already know in advance both the kind of installation and the details of it.
This should end, for example in a kernel execution over a line similar to this:

kernel vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img ks=cdrom:/ks/ks_mode.cfg text device=eth0 ip= netmask= gateway= hostname= Zone=Europe/Rome password=

Where: ,,, &  are FIXED and KNOWN in advance.

So the above line is completely known BEFORE VM starting.

Is it possible to use VBoxManage to start a VM that bypasses grub menu to be manually filled,
and installs Linux OS directly with the chosen (known in advance) configuration?
In other terms, having the details of installation known in advance is it possible to lead
installation process completely in batch mode?

Thank you in advance,
    /A.

Comment: maybe [kickstart](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/ch-kickstart2.html) could help you here

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there is a way to specify the configurations for the installation. But if all you want to achieve is automation of the installation, then you can definitely clone the virtual machine image after the first installation and create as many VMs as you want. I'm not sure if this answers your question, but hope this helps.